# Flex property justify-content: flex-start not working in unordered list (ul)

Tags: css, flexbox

Why won't the items `justify-content: flex-start` within the `ul`? Please help!
https://findmyreleaseliner.vfideacenter.com/product-category/medical/

```
#left-area ul.products {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please add enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Notice that `li.product-category.product` has `auto` margins applied. Details here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276

Comment: Great eye Michael you saved the day!

Comment: You can remove `float: left:` from the `li` elements too. I was going to point out margin but @Michael_B beat me to it ;)